# Loading sDNA toolbox in ArcGIS 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

As I loaded sDNA as a plug-in in ArcGIS 10.6 following the instructions, I found most of the tools invalid as the screencut shows. And the tools that seem loaded normally, like the network preparation report error when I load a network file. Are there any problems with my installation?

[image]

Comment: A cross could mean a broken path, if you look at the properties and the source does where it points to actually exist?

Comment: I suspect the fact some of these work but not others means there is a change in the ArcGIS API somewhere for the user interface components used by each tool. Hence an update to sDNA is required to fix this.

In the meantime it's currently working for me on ArcMap 10.3 and QGIS 2.14

Comment: Thank you for your kind reminding~ I have reinstalled a earlier version yet it remains the same... I would try contacting the developer for further information. Thank you anyway:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xy1427 and myself figured this out - changing language of ArcMap from Chinese to English fixes the problem. Bugfix to follow!